# Create a regex pattern to obtain text between @ and ,

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to create a regex pattern to get the text that is between the following @ and ,. For example the text is something like this:

```
Hello @bob, my name is @jack,
```

What I want to do is get the names `bob` and `jack` out of the string. Reading elsewhere I believe regex (PHP) is the best option. I have created my own pattern, but it does not work. The code I have is bellow. The comment variable contains the text.

```
$pat = '/\@\,/';
preg_match($pat, $comment, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your regex does not work because it only matches `@,` sequence. You want something that is in-between.

You can use the following regex:

```
(?<=@)[^,]+
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/wA2wR8/1)

**Regex explanation**:

- `(?<=@)` - A look-behind that checks if there is a `@` symbol before the text we are going to match with...
- `[^,]+` - a negated character class that matches 1 or more characters other than a comma

[IDEONE demo](https://ideone.com/WFABie):

```
$re = "/(?<=@)[^,]+/"; 
$str = "Hello @bob, my name is @jack,"; 
preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

Comment: Cool that's working one last thing if I want to store them in a each in a variable say $v1 = bob, $v2 = Jack creating new variable each time a new name is found how would I do that

Comment: I think an array is very convenient to store multiple values. If you want to use separate variables, declare them beforehand, and assign the values from `$matches` in a loop.

Comment: Im attempting that at the minute, basically the names will then be used to search a database and retrieve the user information. What im currently trying only seems to get either bob or b and a